# Ctrl-c Not stopping Tomcat using Git Bash

Tags: tomcat, git-bash

As the title says, I'm running Tomcat on Git Bash using Windows 7 and I am unable to close the server using Ctrl-c.  When I press it, the cursor disappears for half a second but other than that nothing happens at all.

EDIT:  Running git bash in VSCode's integrated terminal allows me to use ctrl-c normally.

EDIT 2: After updating to 2.18 at certain times during the build I can stop it with ctrl-c,  However not after the server has started up.  ctrl-c works properly at all time when I'm using git bash in VSCode's integrated terminal.

SOLUTION: I was using the git-bash in the git folder and if I just switch to bash located in the bin everything works fine.  This is why VSCode was working (I had  it set up to use that one)

Comment: Have you tried using startup/shutdown scripts? The second one stops Tomcat for sure.

Comment: I have a ./run_tomcat and a ./stop_tomcat (I assume these are what you're talking about), but would like the ability to stop a build before it is finished.  Its not the end of the world to wait for the build to finish, but it does waste a few minutes each time and if the build ever got stuck it wouldn't be fun.

Answer (score 9):

that was also happen to me for some time

**Ctrl-C** not killing the process or stop asking for input in **GitBash**

then I realize I was pressing **Ctrl-C** like I always pressed but

In **GitBash**

it takes more time to kill the process

So, Press **Ctrl-C** for 1 or 1.5 or even 2 seconds

that worked in my case

I am hoping that will work for you too

for your information.

My Current Version is: Git 2.16

**UPDATE**

It also can happen for not updating the version

I just updated it and it working fine

My Current Version is: Git 2.18

Comment: Somehow none of this works,  I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Update your Git, then try the solutions

Comment: By none of this works, I meant I updated to 2.18 and still it didn't work.  Using bash.exe in the bin I can get ctrl-c to work but still not using git-bash.exe

Comment: Your suggestion has worked for me. Only one thing I would add - in my case I should not have to press long `Ctrl + C`, but I just had to have to wait until next iteration my infinite loop.

Comment: You know problems varies from machine to machine, smiles.

Comment: Try updating it.
Sometimes updating solve the problem. Once updating solve my problem

Comment: For me, using git bash as pycharm terminal, I was seeing that Ctrl+C was apparently not generating KeyBoardInterrupt on a python input() call, but after removing the default action of Ctrl+C in pycharm terminal (reassigning to Ctrl+Shift+C), I see that Ctrl+C followed by Enter generated the KeyBoardInterrupt, only it was not breaking out of the python input() call immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem `git-bash` could not stop `maven` with `ctrl-c`.

After checking the shortcut in the start menu it was clear that the link to `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` was used.

After switching to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`, maven could be stopped with `ctrl-c` without any problems.

---

**Versions**

Git: 2.26.2.windows.1

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Good point, although this was already described as the SOLUTION in the question text. Note that "bash.exe" is the same as "sh.exe", at least in Git version 2.25. Anyway, the problems seems to be in **mintty.exe** then, because that is launched by "git-bash.exe" and this mintty thing seems to be broken in more ways than just non-functioning `ctrl+c`...

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 2021:**

Updated GIT bash to the latest version.
Now I can exit with **CTRL+C**.
It might not work perfectly with the latest versions...

Comment: No luck for me on version 2.23.0 when trying to stop Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat

Comment: No luck for me either

Answer (score 0):

Updating to version 2.33.0 fixed my problem. now CTRL+c works fine.

Answer (score -1):

USE bash from **C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe** instead of using bash from C:\Program Files\Git. It resolves the issue.